# cannot load html text into div tag using jquery in Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Many thanks for your help and support in advance. Using vaadin 7 AbstractJavaScriptComponent, I am trying to load html snippet in place of div tag and the screen does not display anything. Could not figure it out the reason. Please help !

```
window.de_vaadin_ui_myapp_MyWidget = function() {

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#content").load("html/NewFile.html");
});

var element = this.getElement();
this.onStateChange = function() {
    element.innerHTML ="<div id=\"content\"></div>";
};

};

the html file is located in the package de.vaadin.ui.myapp.MyWidget.html
```

Comment: Could you please indicate which of the alternatives in the accepted answer actually helped you solve the problem? In that way, someone else with a similar problem will have an easier way of knowing where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things that could go wrong here. It would help if you'd describe any relevant log messages or such.

I can see multiple different reasons for why this isn't working for you:

1. The connector logic is not run at all e.g. because of a typo in the `@JavaScript` annotation value or the name of the connector function (i.e. `de_vaadin_ui_myapp_MyWidget`). You can verify that it's actually loaded by adding e.g. `console.log(this.getElement())` inside the top level function.
2. The HTML is requested from the wrong URL. Check the network inspector in the browser's developer tools to see which absolute URL is actually loaded and whether that returns the expected result or only e.g. a 404 response. If this is the problem, you could either move the HTML file to some other place or change the relative URL passed to `load` to something
3. The contents of the extended element is reset every time there is a state change event because `innerHTML` is reassigned. It might help to move the statement that assigns `innerHTML` outside of the `onStateChange` handler so that it would only be run once during initialization. This might also cause a situation where `$("#content")` is run before the div has even been created, causing it to not find the target element.